# Where can I find Apple authorized DIY repair manuals?

Tags: hardware, repair, applecare

Apple did not release repair manuals to people without formal training in the past. I hear this has changed.

Where can I find the Apple authorized repair manuals for DIY repairs?

Answer (score 3):

The Apple manuals web site that contains the getting started and existing user manuals also houses the official repair manuals.

- https://support.apple.com/en_US/manuals/repair-manual

You can search for them all or by keyword (just keep repair manuals singular).

Comment: +1 but the cynic in me does think that the 'right to repair' will actually equate to a 'right to completely break it & have to buy a new one' ;)

Comment: Apple is serious here, they even will rent the very expensive 80 pounds of tools to do iPhone screen repairs properly. https://www.macrumors.com/2022/04/27/self-service-repair-iphone-massiive-kit/ @Tetsujin some people that over estimated their skill have certainly turned the “right to repair” into “right to despair”.

Comment: Good resource! +1